# Copy values if checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, html

**I need to add the JavaScript code to enable auto-complete on this form.**
Whenever the checkbox is checked, the code should automatically copy the values from Shipping Name and Shipping Zip into the Billing Name and Billing Zip. If the checkbox is unchecked, the Billing Name and Billing Zip should go blank.
Why my code doesn't work?

My HTML and JS codes are below:

```js
function billingFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById('same').checked) {
    var shipinfo = document.getElementById('shippingName', 'shippingZip').value;
    var billinfo = document.getElementById('billingName', 'billingZip').value;
    shipinfo = billinfo;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('billingName', 'billingZip').value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>JavaScript</h1>
<p> Whenever the checkbox is checked, the code should automatically copy the values from Shipping Name and Shipping Zip into the Billing Name and Billing Zip. If the checkbox is unchecked, the Billing Name and Billing Zip should go blank.</p>

<form>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Shipping Information</legend>
    <label for="shippingName">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="shipName" id="shippingName" required><br/>
    <label for="shippingZip">Zip code:</label>
    <input type="text" name="shipZip" id="shippingZip" pattern="[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="checkbox" id="same" name="same" onchange="billingFunction()" />
  <label for="same">Is the Billing Information the Same?</label>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Billing Information</legend>
    <label for="billingName">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="billName" id="billingName" required><br/>
    <label for="billingZip">Zip code:</label>
    <input type="text" name="billZip" id="billingZip" pattern="[0-9]{5}" required><br/>
  </fieldset>
  <input type="submit" value="Verify" />
</form>
```

Comment: Please post code as a snippet in the question, not as an image.

Comment: Sorry guys for previous wrong question with "picture" :)

Comment: _"Why my code doesn't work?"_ - Why do you think it _"doesn't work"_? What happens? What happens instead? Any errors? Can you convert the parts in your question (markup, script) into a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) that shows the same behavior as your actual script?

Comment: `document.getElementById('shippingName','shippingZip')` that's not how `.getElementById()` works. As it name already suggests it will at most return one element, not multiple. Have a look at `.querySelectorAll()` (and how to work with the returned collection)

Comment: I got it. Thanks, but why it doesn't work when I try to use getElementsByClassName ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function billingFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById('same').checked) {
    var shipinfo = document.getElementById('shippingName').value;
    var billinfo = document.getElementById('shippingZip').value;

    document.getElementById('billingName').value = shipinfo;
    document.getElementById('billingZip').value = billinfo;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('billingName').value = '';
    document.getElementById('billingZip').value = '';
  }
}
```

use this